# Windows 10 Mobile Geolocation settings issue

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have several applications that use geolocation.
When I access the functionality, the popup to confirm the permission appears as described in the documentation and setting yes or no works fine.

But the app doesn't appear in the location settings then, so I cannot switch it on and off at will.

I noticed that it's the case for all my apps (8.1 and 10) but also for the apps on the phone like Here Maps, or Here Drive.

For example I denied Here drive permission on first launch, and I cannot switch it back on as it doesn't appear in the settings.

Do you notice the same behavior or is there a specific line to add to make it appear ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: You should be able to change this under "Settings"->"Privacy"->"Location" for every app. Btw there is also a Protocol activation URI to open these settings directly from your app: ms-settings:privacy-location
More here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465148.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, I should be able to. But only a few apps are appearing in the Location settings (News, Cortana, Facebook and Edge). All the others apps are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Is the Location capability added to the missing apps? (e.g. if you create one in Visual Studio... and you also add the capability to the app.. is the app there?)

Comment: Yes it is, and the location permission confirmation popup appears as intended, in the apps and I can use the geolocator if the permission is granted. It just doesn't appear in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This was just a bug of the OS.
Hard resetting my phone solved the problem.